# Unexpected T_IF syntax error

Tags: php

I am currently working on a PHP script to upload an image to a mysql database and I am getting a syntax error on line 13 of my code that states Unexpected T_IF. I am relatively new to PHP and I am struggling to work out what is causing it. The code is as follows;

```
    <head>
        <title>File Upload To Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image"><Input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>

        <?php>
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                mysql_connect("localhost","appuser1","******");
                mysql_select_db("PHP_Sig_test_app");

                $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($FILES["image"]["name"]);
                $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
                $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($FILES["image"]["type""]);

                if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image)
                {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Data' Values('','$imageName','$imageData')";
                    echo "image uploaded";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Only Images can be Inserted"
                }    
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: There's an extra quote `$imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($FILES["image"]["type""]);`

Comment: Just look closely at how SO highlighted your code. Also, it's a good idea to use an editor that highlights syntax and underlines errors (there are plenty of options).

Comment: Please stop using the ***Deprecated*** `mysql` extension, it's no longer supported, it's going to be removed, and is replaced with either one of 2 extensions: `PDO` and `mysqli` (the `i` stands for _improved_). PS: syntax errors (and other simple typographical errors) are deemed off-topic on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have some syntax errors -

```
<?php //removed >

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            mysql_connect("localhost","appuser1","weeble180276");
            mysql_select_db("PHP_Sig_test_app");

            $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
            $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($FILES["image"]["type"]); //removed "

            if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") //added "
            {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Data' Values('','$imageName','$imageData')";
                echo "image uploaded";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Only Images can be Inserted"; // added ;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hmm.. there are some missing `"` & `;` also.

Comment: This seems to have worked, but the problem I am having now is that the HTML form section is not even being displayed in the browser, any ideas as to why?

Comment: Is that html code in the right place?? I mean as it is in the question??

Comment: I have now separated them in to different documents, one being the HTML script that links to the php, I am getting a syntax error saying "unexpected T_String" where it says "if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")" in the PHP part of the script now, any ideas?

Comment: Please show more codes.

Answer (score 2):

`<?php>` should be `<?php`

Thats causing the syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Remove the closing bracket in this line:

```
<?php>
```

This starts a new command with the `>` sign (which makes of cause no sense) so `> if` will fail and this is the reason for your bug.

Your second if statment also has a missing quote.

```
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image)
```

should be

```
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, but the problem I am having now is that the HTML form section is not even being displayed in the browser, any ideas as to why?